# Getting a node and its specific sub node

Tags: java, xml, xpath, domxpath

I am trying to get a node and specific sub node. Let's say I have below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
<person>
  <property>number one</property>
  <csvname>
     <name>one</name>
   </csvname>
  <first>Yash</first>
  <last>M</last>
  <age>22</age>
</person>
<person>
  <property>number two</property>
  <csvname>
     <name>two</name>
   </csvname>
  <first>Bill</first>
  <last>Gates</last>
  <age>46</age>
</person>
<person>
  <property>number three</property>
  <csvname>
     <name>three</name>
   </csvname>
  <first>Steve</first>
  <last>Jobs</last>
  <age>40</age>
</person>
</book>
```

I want to get root element along with matching person element(lets say person having name=one ), ie output like this :

```
<person>
  <property>number one</property>
</person>
```

How can I get above output using Java xpath.

I have tried several xpath expression but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the xpath.

```
 //name[.='one']/ancestor::person
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. @supputuri. your xpath exp is getting all the other sub elements of person (which are csvname, first, last & age), which i dont want.

Comment: Ohh, ok. So you want only, person and property nodes?

Comment: Yes please. I am just looking for person and property nodes

Comment: `//person[.//name[.='one']]/*[local-name()='property']` is the one which will give only property, I will jump on this aftersometime.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no direct xpath by which you can get parent and specific child. `Option1:` You can try the getting the parent node as mentioned in the answer and then remove the unwanted nodes from the xpath output. `Option 2:` if you are sure the `<person>` does not have any attributes then you can wrap the child node from `//person[.//name[.='one']]/*[local-name()='property']` in custom `person` tag.